# ClassNotFoundException

Tags: java, android

Как пофиксить эту ошибку?

```
08-25 04:03:34.080 2276-2276/? I/art: Not late-enabling -Xcheck:jni (already on)
08-25 04:03:35.144 2276-2276/? D/AndroidRuntime: Shutting down VM


--------- beginning of crash
08-25 04:03:35.145 2276-2276/? E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: com.android.tencent.zdevs.bah, PID: 2276
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate activity ComponentInfo{com.android.tencent.zdevs.bah/com.android.tencent.zdevs.bah.MainActivity}: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "com.android.tencent.zdevs.bah.MainActivity" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/com.android.tencent.zdevs.bah-2/base.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/vendor/lib64, /system/lib64]]
 at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2236)
 at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2387)
 at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:151)
 at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1303)
 at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
 at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
 at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5254)
 at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
 at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
 at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:903)
 at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:698)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "com.android.tencent.zdevs.bah.MainActivity" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/com.android.tencent.zdevs.bah-2/base.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/vendor/lib64, /system/lib64]]
 at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(BaseDexClassLoader.java:56)
 at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:511)
 at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:469)
 at android.app.Instrumentation.newActivity(Instrumentation.java:1066)
 at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2226)
 at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2387)
 at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:151)
 at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1303)
 at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
 at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
 at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5254)
 at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
 at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
 at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:903)
 at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:698)
Suppressed: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.android.tencent.zdevs.bah.MainActivity
 at java.lang.Class.classForName(Native Method)
 at java.lang.BootClassLoader.findClass(ClassLoader.java:781)
 at java.lang.BootClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:841)
 at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:504)
        ... 13 more
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Class not found using the boot class loader; no stack available
```

Manifest

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.android.tencent.zdevs.bah">


  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE"/>


  <application
      android:allowBackup="true"
      android:icon="@drawable/first_icon"
      android:label="@string/app_name"
      android:persistent="true"
      android:theme="@style/Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
    <activity
        android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan">
      <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN"/>
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER"/>
      </intent-filter>
    </activity>

    <activity-alias
        android:name=".QQ1279525738"
        android:enabled="false"
        android:icon="@drawable/second_icon"
        android:label="@string/second_activity_name"
        android:targetActivity=".MainActivity">
      <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN"/>
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER"/>
      </intent-filter>
    </activity-alias>
  </application>
</manifest>
```

Comment: Можно скинуть манфест сюда? Выглядит, так, как будто в нём неправильно прописано свойство android:name самого MainActivity или что либо еще с этим связанное.

Answer (score 0):

Сначало "Clean" и "Sync Project with Gradle Files". Потом запускай код.
    Ещё можешь попробывать это: File -> Settings -> Build, Execution, Deployment -> Instant Run